# How to fix a CORS error while request an API with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

The goal of this project is to authenticate users with Azure Active Directory using .NET Core 2.2

I manage to authenticate the user by directly making a request in my browser.
For example, if I call 'http://localhost:44353/api/azureauth' from my browser, I have no problem.

But if I call it from an Angular project I get the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44353%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}'
(redirected from 'https://localhost:44353/api/azureauth/me') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44353%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce} with MIME type text/html. 
See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Here is my Startup.cs :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                );
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        }
```

Here is one of my controller :

```
    [Route("api/[controller]"), EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AzureAuthController
    {
        public IActionResult Me()
        {
            return new JsonResult("ok");
        }
    }
```

Here is the service in Angular that calls the .NET Core API :

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': '',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AzureAuthService {

  private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44353/api/azureauth';

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public me() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, httpOptions).
      pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return data;
        }, (err) => {
          console.log('An error occured', err);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I do not understand the problem, knowing that I allow all origins and methods, both in Angular's query and in CORS management in the .NET Core API

I mention that the project is the Azure AD sample project with ASP.NET Core (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg)
Thank you for your answers

Comment: OpenID Connect + cookie authentication (which you use here) is not really suitable for APIs. You should instead implement JWT Bearer token authentication and have your front-end handle auth and token acquisition with e.g. MSAL.js.

Comment: I prefer this solution.
Do I have the choice or there is no solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to review the info you provided as "Audience".

Open appsettings.json
Grab the bearer token that your Angular App received and paste it into the form at jwt.io.
For Audience, enter the value found under “aud” there.
For Issuer, enter the value found under "iss" there.

More information here (step 7): https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/07/11/securing-your-web-api-using-azure-active-directory/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been suggested, you need a Active Directory Authentication Library like ADAL or MSAL to perform the authentication process.

Register a client application and enable the OAuth2 implicit grant for it to access to your API. See this code sample project: [Call an Azure AD protected Web API in an AngularJS Single Page App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi#call-an-azure-ad-protected-web-api-in-an-angularjs-single-page-app).

Comment: I managed to get a token with MSAL in my Angular App.
But when i send it to the .NET Core App, i always get a 401.
In the logs, i get : 
AzureADJwtBearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed